# How to find hadoop applications ran by oozie (hadoop) job

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, oozie, oozie-coordinator, oozie-workflow

We know that first oozie runs a hadoop job and using that job it runs other hadoop applications. So I want to find the list of those hadoop applications (eg. application_231232133) ran by oozie (hadoop) job. Currently there is no such api or command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Oozie 5.0 or higher then the application type of those jobs is "Oozie Launcher", not "MapReduce" so they are easy to filter out.

Answer (score 0):

You may use Oozie REST API http://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/WebServicesAPI.html#Job_Information which return externalId attribute for each action filled by hadoop application id.